# Tyni MCE path not saved corectly

Tags: tinymce

I have tiny mce 3.5.8 embedded in my site and i use it to upload the content of my pages.When i add the url for an image it saves is as "/upload/gree-forest-wallpaper.jpg" instead of
"../admin/upload/gree-forest-wallpaper.jpg ".What's the problem ?